# Google Chrome asking for username+password for ApplicationPoolIdentity

Tags: google-chrome, windows-authentication

I am running .NET C# v2.0 website on Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 6.1.

The site is using only Windows Authentication with the following configuration:
Extended Protection:Off
Enable Kernel-mode authentication: Checked
Providers Order: 1. NTLM; 2. Negotiate

The AppPool Identity has Full Control access on the website's directory and also on the SQL Server DB.

The site works fine with IE, but in Chrome it prompts endlessly for username and password. On cancel, it goes to 401 error. Nothing appears in the EventLog.

When I switch the AppPool Identity to Network Service, the prompt jumps up only once and when I hit cancel, the website loads.

What can be the cause of the problem?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to clear browser cache

try this

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar. In the dialog that
  appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you
  want to remove.
- Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data
  that you want to delete.
- Select beginning of time to **delete**
  everything.

Comment: It didn't help.
Also, all my clients have the same problem, so I don't think it's cache.

Comment: it said 'Do not retry without fixing the problem. You need to get a new auth token.' https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors

Comment: I'm not sure what it means. How can I know I fixed the problem without  retrying?